# Print dictionary value into string with Python3.6

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary like the following:

```
{'keyid': ['foo', '1', 'bar', '2', '(FancyStrininParathesis)']}
```

How could I extract the strings in the value of the dictionary and create and print one long string such as

```
 print (finalstring)  #Desired output:  'foo - 1 bar - 2 (FancyStrininParathesis)'
```

I've been able to output the value fine, but I can't figure out how to output the array as one long string. I'm new to python as well, I'm more familer with PHP, however I have to use a special python library for this project.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by comma seperated string ? The value for key `keyid` is an array

Comment: Check out [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)!

Comment: @Xatyrian like I said I'm new at Python! Didn't occur to me that that was an array!. Either way- how would I go about achieving the desired final string with the values in that array?

Comment: @brent20 well, you would iterate through the array like you do in PHP ;) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your reply to my comment, I think I understand what you want to do. With

```
dictionnary = {'keyid': ['foo', '1', 'bar', '2', '(FancyStrininParathesis)']}
```

you can iterate through the values with `dictionnary.items()`:

```
for key, value in dictionnary.items():
    ...
```

Now because here `value` is a list, we can iterate through it and create our own output string:

```
for key, value in dictionnary.items():
    output = ""
    for item in value:
        output += item + " - "
    output = output[:-3] # Remove the last three characters
    print(output)
```

A more pythonic way would be to use `str.join`:

```
for key, value in dictionnary.items():
    output = str.join(" - ", value)
    print(output)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! I think I can handle the rest on my own- if I didn't want a - after the last string (2 in this example) before the (FancyStringInParathesis) how would I not include it there? Your pythonic example makes perfect sense and works great if I want the hyphen between all the strings, but how would I handle that last one?

Comment: @brent20 `str.join` only prints characters between items of the list so you don't have to worry, if you want to add a last one after all the items you can just append it to the string

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
d = {'keyid': ['foo', '1', 'bar', '2', '(FancyStrininParathesis)']}
' - '.join(d['keyid'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dicttt = {'keyid': ['foo', '1', 'bar', '2', '(FancyStrininParathesis)']}

entr = dicttt["keyid"] # get the list from the dictionary

print( ' - '.join(entr)) # join each lists entry by ' - ' and print all
```

or if you simply want to output it you can output it by iterating the list and printing without newlines:

```
for n in range(len(entr)): # get an index into the list
    if (n > 0):
        print(' - ',end="") # if index > 0 print seperator, no newline

    print(entr[n] ,end="") # print list item, no newline

print() # print newline
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
dt ={'keyid': ['foo', '1', 'bar', '2', '(FancyStrininParathesis)']}
for x in dt.values():
    s =' '.join(x)

s
print(s)
```